# Durandal build the route based on userRole

Tags: javascript, durandal

what am i doing wrong here a want to build a navigation based on userRole
UPDATE: result are object **console.log(result);**
[image]
**console.log(JSON.stringify(result));** gives me this back

```
function activate() {
    console.log(appsecurity.userInfo());

    if (typeof (appsecurity.userInfo()) === 'Administrator'){
        return privateAccess();

    } else {
        return publicAccess();
    }

    router.on('router:route:not-found', function (fragment) {
        logError('No Route Found', fragment, true); 
    });
}

var courses = [
    { route: '', title:'Welcome', moduleId: 'viewmodels/welcome', nav: true, type: 'guest' , authorize: ["User", "Administrator"]},
    { route: 'flickr', moduleId: 'viewmodels/flickr', nav: true, authorize: ["User"] },
    { route: 'youtube', moduleId: 'viewmodels/youtube', nav: true, type: 'member' },
    { route: 'facebook', moduleId: 'viewmodels/facebook', nav: true, authorize: ["Administrator"] },
    { route: 'skype', moduleId: 'viewmodels/skype', nav: true, authorize: ["User", "Administrator"] }
] ;  

var acceptedTypes = ["Administrator", "Visitor"];

var result = (function(authTypes) {
    var results = [], i, j, k, works;

    for(i=0; i<courses.length; i++) {
        if(courses[i]&&courses[i].authorize&&courses[i].authorize.length) {
            works = false;
            for(j=0; j<courses[i].authorize.length; j++) {
                for(k=0; k<authTypes.length; k++) {
                    works = works || courses[i].authorize[j] === authTypes[k];
                }
            }

            if(works)
                results.push(courses[i]);
        }
    }

    return results;
}) (acceptedTypes);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); 

function privateAccess() {
    return router.map(result)            // Map the routes
        .buildNavigationModel() // Finds all nav routes and readies them
        //TODO!?: .mapUnknownRoutes("notfound","notfound")
        .mapUnknownRoutes('account/login', 'not-found')
        .activate();            // Activate the router
        //.activate({ pushState: true });
}
```

then this will not work  the **data-bind="foreach: router.navigationModel"** is **EMPTY** and i can not see any error in the console

```
var routesArray = JSON.stringify(result);
router.makeRelative({ moduleId: 'viewmodels' }); // router will look here for viewmodels by convention
router.map(routesArray).buildNavigationModel();

return router.makeRelative({ moduleId: 'viewmodels' }).map(routesArray).mapUnknownRoutes('account/login', 'not-found').buildNavigationModel();
```

but this will work

```
router.makeRelative({ moduleId: 'viewmodels' }); // router will look here for viewmodels by convention

router.map([
    { route: '', title:'Welcome', moduleId: 'viewmodels/welcome', nav: true, type: 'guest' , authorize: ["User", "Administrator"]},
    { route: 'flickr', moduleId: 'viewmodels/flickr', nav: true, authorize: ["User"] },
    { route: 'youtube', moduleId: 'viewmodels/youtube', nav: true, type: 'member' },
    { route: 'facebook', moduleId: 'viewmodels/facebook', nav: true, authorize: ["Administrator"] }
    { route: 'skype', moduleId: 'viewmodels/skype', nav: true, authorize: ["User", "Administrator"] }
]).buildNavigationModel();

return router;
```

Comment: Why are you passing a stringified array to `router.map`?  Is it possible that `var routesArray = JSON.stringify(result);` should be parsing instead of stringifying?

Comment: because the example 2 is working fine and since routesArray = JSON.stringify(result); i i was thinking that will work just like in example 2

Comment: The second code sample in [Using The Router](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router.html) shows routers receiving a decoded array.

Comment: i tried router.map().apply(this, routesArray).buildNavigationModel(); but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from @mike-samuel is right. `JSON.stringify` will return you a string. When you pass a string to the router, it presumes that the string represents route. Here's the code from `router.map`; in your case you're using 'route' as a string, and you're not passing in a 'config' object, so the router will create a config for you and set your "route" (stringified array) as the route parameter:

```
router.map = function(route, config) {
    if (system.isArray(route)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < route.length; i++) {
            router.map(route[i]);
        }

        return router;
    }

    if (system.isString(route) || system.isRegExp(route)) {
        if (!config) {
            config = {};
        } else if (system.isString(config)) {
            config = { moduleId: config };
        }

        config.route = route;
    } else {
        config = route;
    }

    return mapRoute(config);
};
```

The router will later go on to try and make a regular expression out of your array and I can only imagine that things are getting messy from here.

It seems suspicious that you're using JSON.stringify to convert whatever object to an "array" (its actually converting it to a string). What was the object beforehand? If its an array already then you should be able to pass it directly to the router:

```
// Map the result directly - do not stringify!
router.map(result).buildNavigationModel();
```

Alternatively, if the result is a string then you'd likely want to do a JSON.parse:

```
// PARSE the result string as an array
var routesArray = JSON.parse(result);
router.makeRelative({ moduleId: 'viewmodels' });
router.map(routesArray).buildNavigationModel();
```

By the way I can't see where your `router` is being declared but I presume that somewhere you're making it a child router rather than trying to use the root router?

```
router = rootRouter.createChildRouter()
```

## EDIT

Based on your updated code, I copied it into my application as follows:

```
var courses = [
    { route: '', title: 'Welcome', moduleId: 'viewmodels/welcome', nav: true, type: 'guest', authorize: ["User", "Administrator"] },
    { route: 'flickr', moduleId: 'viewmodels/flickr', nav: true, authorize: ["User"] },
    { route: 'youtube', moduleId: 'viewmodels/youtube', nav: true, type: 'member' },
    { route: 'facebook', moduleId: 'viewmodels/facebook', nav: true, authorize: ["Administrator"] },
    { route: 'skype', moduleId: 'viewmodels/skype', nav: true, authorize: ["User", "Administrator"] }
];

var acceptedTypes = ["Administrator", "Visitor"];

var result = (function (authTypes) {
    var results = [], i, j, k, works;

    for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
        if (courses[i] && courses[i].authorize && courses[i].authorize.length) {
            works = false;
            for (j = 0; j < courses[i].authorize.length; j++) {
                for (k = 0; k < authTypes.length; k++) {
                    works = works || courses[i].authorize[j] === authTypes[k];
                }
            }

            if (works)
                results.push(courses[i]);
        }
    }

    return results;
})(acceptedTypes);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

var child = rootRouter.createChildRouter();
child.map(result).buildNavigationModel();

var nav = child.navigationModel;

debugger;
```

At the debugger, when I evaluated `nav()` there were three links in there, and I was able to bind them to my view. There were a few mismatched quotes in your original source code - perhaps that's what was throwing you?

Comment: i made some update to the code can you please check it router.map(result).buildNavigationModel(); is not working

Comment: Can you be more specific? As I said, that **exact** code is working for me, and its based on the code you provided. Do you have a URL that we could hit somewhere to have a look at your solution? There must be another piece of the puzzle missing.

Comment: return router.map(result).buildNavigationModel().mapUnknownRoutes('account/login', 'not-found'); is working fine thank you for your help

Comment: Awesome - glad that we got there in the end :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48644/discussion-between-gerrod-and-kougiland)

Comment: can you please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127078/how-to-search-with-knockout

Answer (score 0):

You log `console.log(JSON.stringify(result));`, but use  `JSON.stringify(resultSetB)`

**resultSetB** instead of **result**