# how to search with knockout

Tags: knockout.js

i am trying to make a very simple search using knockout in a Durandal project.
[Demo in Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/4UgpX/15/)

1. What am i doing wrong here?
2. Is there a better way to implement search ?

   ```
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=the+Cat+In+The+Hat";

       $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
           console.log(data.items);
           var books = data.items;
      var viewModel = {
       query: ko.observable('')
       };
        viewModel.model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.items);
      viewModel.books = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
       var search = this.query().toLowerCase();
       return ko.utils.arrayFilter(books, function(book) {
           return book.kind.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0 || book.brewery.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0 || book.style.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
       });
   }, viewModel);
           ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
       });
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1: What am i doing wrong here?

There are few mistakes in your code which is clearly visible to me:

- You added *ko.mapping* plugin before *knocout.js*. Mapping plugin should added after knockout.js.
- In your js code you are using *JSON.stringify* which convert the response json object to json string. No need to convert it, just use as it is.

> 2: Is there a better way to implement search ?

I have created a fiddle to demonstrate a slightly better approach of searching according to your scenario.

**Note:** *I used the latest stable version of knockout i.e. 3.0.0 and i recommend you to always use the latest version. You used dependentObservable in your code but Since Knockout 2.0, dependent observables are now called [computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html).*

[Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/bofiqayo/2/edit?output) (If fiddle not works than you should provide your api key in javascript code)

*Main view model*

```
function viewModel()
{
  var self = this;
  var key = "your api key";

  self.query = ko.observable("the cat is in the hat").extend({ throttle: 500 });

  self.books = ko.observableArray();

  self.get = function() { 
     $.ajax({
            url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes",
            data: { q: self.query(), key: key },
            type: "GET",
            success: function (response) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(response.items, {
                    create: function(options) {
                       return new book(options.data);
                    }
                }, self.books);
            }
      });
  };

  self.search = ko.computed(function() {
    if(self.query() !== "")
      self.get();
  });
}
```

*Book object*

```
function book(data)
{
  var self = this;

  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self); 

  //here you can add extra properties in book object if needed
}
```

*Apply bindings*

```
$(function(){
  var vm = new viewModel();
  vm.get();                   //get initial data
  ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

**Note:** *Currently this code is not handling proper messages on error, on books not found, input query validation etc etc. You should handle it by yourself in order to provide better user experience.*

**Edit**

I updated your code in fiddle [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/4UgpX/20/) its working.

Comment: ok thank you for the answer but i made some update to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/4UgpX/15/ and i would like to stay on the same view as in the main question. Your code is a way to long for what i have to do after with it

Comment: @kougiland i updated your fiddle, check my edited answer

Comment: do you know why when i want to search 1 step down in the tree it doesn't work anymore? http://jsfiddle.net/95wTn/3/

Comment: I check your fiddle its working, here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/95wTn/4/, in this fiddle the searching is only on textSnippet. Do i missing something ??

Comment: yes i want to search for id,kind,etag and searchInfo.textSnippet  when i remove searchInfo.textSnippet it works fine

Comment: but in your fiddle the search is working as expected without removing `searchInfo.textSnippet`, enter `VTu8i9vGUksC` in your search box you will get the matched result

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48838/discussion-between-kougiland-and-gaurav)